# React context return undefined

Tags: reactjs

I am using React Context api to pass some states to different child components and it's returning `undefined`.

Parent component:

```
export const UserContext = React.createContext();
export class Provider extends Component {
  state = {
    editGroup: false,
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <UserContext.Provider value={{
        state: this.state
      }}>
        {this.props.children}
      </UserContext.Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

Child component:

```
import { UserContext } from './index';

return (
  <React.Fragment>
    <UserContext.Consumer>
      {(context) => (
        <p>im inside the consumer {console.log(context)}</p>
      )}
    </UserContext.Consumer>
  </React.Fragment>
);
```

This last `console.log` is returning as `undefined`, what am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: are you using redux? If so, you shouldn't use context

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the child component change context to value (function parameter) in the Consumer section as thats is the prop passed to the Provider

```
<UserContext.Consumer>
  {(value) => ( 
    <p>im inside the consumer {console.log(value)}</p>
  )}
</UserContext.Consumer>
```

Full working sample

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
    const UserContext = React.createContext()

    const Main = () => (
      <Parent>
        <Child/>
      </Parent>
    )

    export default Main

    //***************************************/

    class Parent extends Component {

      state = {
        editGroup: false
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <UserContext.Provider value={{
            state: this.state
          }}>
            {this.props.children}
          </UserContext.Provider>
        )
      }
    }

    //***************************************/

    const Child = () => {
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <UserContext.Consumer>
            {(value) => (
              <p>Inside consumer {console.log(value)}</p>
            )}
          </UserContext.Consumer>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    }

    //***************************************/
```

Output: state: {editGroup: false}

Comment: I missed context in the console statement. Updated answer.

Comment: Yes, i noticed hehe... but this isnt the problem.

Comment: Using `useContext()` in the `Child` class should return the values of the context right?

Answer (score 27):

Also, make sure to pass context in the constructor if you override it!

```
    export default class Profile extends React.Component {
        static contextType = AuthContext;
        // make sure you pass the context along to super!
        constructor(props, context) {
            super(props, context);
            ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you please explain why? i was trying to find the solution and your's work

Comment: We inherit functionality from the base class React.Component. The constructor in that class expects props and context. If we override the constructor in our class we need to make sure to pass all the expected arguments along to super (the base class constructor) to retain all functionality and let the instance know about the context it should rely on

Comment: I needed to do this, although I'm told it's deprecated.  Thanks @KennethLynne, saved my day.

Answer (score 4):

You need to provide a context default value in createContext()

Like

```
export const UserContext = React.createContext('default');
```

Or

```
export const UserContext = React.createContext({ctx_key:"ctx_value"});
```

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue myself recently.  In my case, I was calling `<MyContext.Consumer>{(context) => /* ... */}</MyContext.Consumer>` from within a portal that was *outside* of my provider.  Composition matters here!

```
<MyContext.Provider>
  /* ... tons and tons of code */

  <MyContext.Consumer>
    {(context) => {
      return (
        <Modal foo={context.foo} />  // gets rendered in a portal, far below the provider, but we've made a closure over it, so it's OK 
      )
    }}
  </MyContext.Consumer>
</MyContext.Provider>
```

Answer (score -1):

I was facing same issue except that it was a functional component with useContext Hook instead of `<ContextProvider.Consumer/>` component. I realized that I was using the context in the immediate descendant component of the ancestor component having states to pass and the point is that we dont need context in the immediate descent because there we already have the props and if we use context React will surely throw errors.
You can further read the Bug here. It will surely help you if your reason of gettig undefined is same as in the discussion here:
https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/18629#issuecomment-1080852523

Also it helps in the problem where you are getting state value in the context of only the default one not the modified one